# Sidebar navigation appears and then disappears on page load when using jquery localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using the jQuery localStorage to remember the toggled state of the sidebar navigation menu using the following 
jQuery code:

```
$('#wrapper').toggleClass(window.localStorage.toggled);
$('#menu-toggle').on('click',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if (window.localStorage.toggled != "toggled" ) 
    {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass("toggled", true );
        window.localStorage.toggled = "toggled";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass("toggled", false );
        window.localStorage.toggled = "";
    }
});
```

The code work properly by remembering the toggled state. The problem arises when the page is refreshed. The sidebar navigation menu first appears and then disappears. I already tried setting the display:none in the css but it doesn't seem to work.

The relevant html code:

```
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a>

<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I would achieve your goal. Note that I have used a snippet to organize the code but it will not work on SO due to sandboxing not allowing access to local storage. However you can see it in action with this..

#### [Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgLcndpf/12/)

```js
/**
 * Feature detect + local reference for simple use of local storage
 * if (storage) {
 *    storage.setItem('key', 'value');
 *    storage.getItem('key');
 * }
 */
var storage;
var fail;
var uid;
try {
  uid = new Date;
  (storage = window.localStorage).setItem(uid, uid);
  fail = storage.getItem(uid) != uid;
  storage.removeItem(uid);
  fail && (storage = false);
} catch (exception) {}
/* end  Feature detect + local reference */

$(function() {

  if (storage) {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('isOpen', storage.getItem('isOpen') == '1');
    $('#menu-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var setOpen = storage.getItem('isOpen') == '1' ? 0 : 1; // set opento the oposite of current
      storage.setItem('isOpen', setOpen);
      $('#wrapper').toggleClass('isOpen', setOpen);
    });
  } 
  
});
```

```css
#wrapper:not(.isOpen) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a>

<div id="wrapper">
  some content here
</div>
```

Comment: Hi DelightedD0D, the code works perfectly on full screen. However when I resize the screen using bootstrap to 768px or lower, the jQuery toggle button stops working. Any idea why it is so? . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FarizAnwardeen Im not sure, The jsFiddle I linked to has bootstrap loaded. I tried making the window as thin as possible (like 100px) and the button still functions as expected. I'd guess that in your actual HTML you have another component or possibly some other CSS that is conflicting with the button (like a transparent div sitting over the button or something like that) but without seeing it actually happen, I couldnt say. If you can make an example fiddle that shows the behaviour, Id be happy to look at it.

Comment: I went through my code and found there was css conflict like you said. Adding  overflow-y: auto; in line 28 causes the toggle to stop working. If I remove that particular line, my sidebar wrapper background color disappears. Also do you know how I can make sidebar visible by default when the user first enters my site. Thanks. Here is the link to the JsFiddle [LINK TO CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/farizanwardeen/8eLa3o9q/)